# Setting Local Environment Variables with POW.cx

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I've installed pow.cx so I can setup local environment variables. I've created the symlink to my app which is working fine.

Here is my environment.rb file

```
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the rails application
Myapp::Application.initialize!

ENV['RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY']
ENV['RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY']
```

What I'm not sure of is how I should add my environment variables to the .powenv file.

My .powenv file.

```
RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY => 1234567890
RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY  => 0987654321
```

Can someone tell me if this is ok because it doesn't work.

I've tried adding export to the front of each line but that adds files to my app directory with my key values.

Here is the documentation for setting environment variables with pow.cx

http://pow.cx/manual.html#section_2.2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
export RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY="1234567890"

export RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY ="0987654321"
```

Comment: Tried that but still no luck. Adds files with the value to my app but doesn't work.

Comment: you were right. I didn't notice that my syntax was in fact incorrect. I had => instead of = so you were right. Thank you.